# Better way to check if Object is of some Type bevor using it as said Type?

Tags: c#, object, if-statement, casting

I have a huge if else statement where an Object is getting check for a specific type bevor it is used in a method. Is there a shorter/more effective way of doing this?

A bit simplified my code looks like this:

```
if(object is class1) someMethod(object as class1);
else if (object is class2) someMethod(object as class2);
else if (object is class3) someMethod(object as class3);
else if (object is class4) someMethod(object as class4);
else if (object is class5) someMethod(object as class5);
.
.
.
```

Comment: Use C# 7 pattern matching https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# 7.0 lets you write this as a switch statement:

```
switch (object)
{
    case Class1 c1:
        someMethod(c1);
        break;
    case Class2 c2:
        someMethod(c2);
        break;
}
```

Alternatively you can use pattern matching in C# 7.0:

```
if (object is Class1 c1) someMethod(c1);
else if (object is Class2 c2) someMethod(c2);
```

If you can change Class1/Class2/etc to implement some visitor interface, you can use the visitor pattern / double dispatch:

```
public interface IClass
{
     void Visit(IClassVisitor visitor);
}

public interface IClassVisitor
{
    void Accept(Class1 c1);
    void Accept(Class2 c2);
}

public class Class1 : IClass
{
    public void Visit(IClassVisitor visitor) => visitor.Accept(this);
}

public class Class2 : IClass
{
    public void Visit(IClassVisitor visitor) => visitor.Accept(this);
}
```

Then implement `IClassVisitor` (and implement `Accept(Class1 c1)` and `Accept(Class2 c2)`), and call:

```
object.Visit(this);
```

and the right overload of `Accept` will be called.

(I'm a particular fan of the visitor pattern, for one simple reason: if you add another implementation of `IClass`, the compiler forces you to update each of visitors, so there's no chance that you'll forget to write some code which handles the new implementation. With the switch statement / if/else, you have to remember all the places where you switch over your `object` and update each of them. In this way, it's feels like much less of a violation of the open/closed principle).